# Order of Natural Numbers in Algorithms

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, contest-math, recursive-algorithms

Could anyone describe, why this is a True statements?

if $f_i$ be a function of natural numbers to natural numbers and $f_i(n)=O(n)$ then $\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} f_i(n)=O(n^2)  $

Comment: The statement is not true as written... see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false as written.  Suppose that each $f_{i}(n)$ satisfies $i^2 n \leq f_{i}(n)\leq 2 i^{2}n$.  Then it is the case that $f_{i}(n)=O(n)$ (you can take the constant for $f_{i}(n)$ to be $2i^2$).  Then, your function $f$ is lower-bounded by $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2 n \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}f_{i}(n)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2 n \sim n^3$.

In order for the statement to be true, you need each $f_{i}(n)$ to be $O(n)$ using one constant for all of them, i.e. $f_{i}(n)\leq Cn$ for all $i$.

EDIT: and, you need the bound to be true for all $n\geq N$ (where the same $N$ works for each $f_{i}$).

Comment: You also need a single constant $N$. Alternatively you can say that the $N_i$ and $C_i$ must be bounded.

Comment: That is true.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph, Which part does not make sense?  I'm happy to expand if you explain what you do/do not understand.

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph, The easiest way to make it true would be to say, instead of each f_i(n)=O(n), that for every i, f_i (n) <= Cn for all n>N (i.e. the same C and N work for every f_i).

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph, the way it is stated now, it is false.

Answer (score 1):

For every $i$, there is an $N_i$ and a $C_i$ such that for all $n\ge N_i$, $f_i(n)\le C_in$.

Then, taking $N=\max_iN_i$ and $C=\max_iC_i$, for all $n\ge N$, $\sum_if_i\le \sum_iCn=Cn^2$.

This reasoning does not hold if the $N_i$ or $C_i$ are unbounded.

Comment: It also works with $C$ being the average of the $C_i$.

Comment: There may be a typo in the problem.  I don't think you can take the max (since you must think of n as going to infinity.  For example, suppose that f_i(n) <= 2i^2 n and f_i(n)>=i^2 n.  Then certainly f_i(n)=O(n), but when you sum them, you get a lower bound of sum i^2 n ~ n^3 (summing over i from 1 to n).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are summing from 1 to n, over a function that already is $O(n)$, you're taking the function $n$ times for every number between $1$ and $n$. This should pop out to you as $n\cdot n = n^2$.